# How to make a custom fullscreen video button that works on both IOS and desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video, fullscreen

I'm a neophyte struggling to build a video website. The site works on desktop and iOS, however in iOS, my fullscreen video button does not work.

If I turn on the "controls" attribute in the  tag, then iOS will display apple's native controls to put the video in fullscreen so i know fullscreen video works for iOS.  The native controls clash with my website layout so i'd prefer not to have them.  when i delete "controls" attribute, they don't display which is good but then there is no way to put the video into fullscreen.

what i would like is for my custom fullscreen button that works on desktop to work on iOS.  I can't seem to tie the button to the iOS code that I pulled out of the Apple dev guidelines.

```
 <video id="tv" autoplay muted controls playsinline autoplay onended="fine()"webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>


<div id="fullscreenbutton" onclick="openFullscreen(); webkitbeginfullscreen(); webkitEnterFullscreen(); addFullscreenButton(); goFullscreen();"></div>

</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var vid;

        function init() {

            vid = document.getElementById("tv");

            vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", addFullscreenButton, false);

        }

        function addFullscreenButton() {

            if (vid.webkitSupportsFullscreen) {

                var fs = document.getElementById("fullscreenbutton");

                fs.style.visibility = "visible";

            }

        }

        function goFullscreen() {

            vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();

        }

    </script>
```

I'm a newbie but I'm hoping when the fullscreen button is clicked, it would go fullscreen video in ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got it to work by using this:

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    play = document.getElementById('play'),
    time;
video.addEventListener('webkitbeginfullscreen', function() {
    play.innerText = 'play fullscreen video';
    window.clearInterval(time);
});
video.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
    video.pause();
});
play.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    time = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            video.webkitEnterFullscreen();
        }
        catch(e) {}
    }, 250);
    play.innerText = 'loading ...';
    video.play();   
});
</script>
```

I found it here:
https://gist.github.com/4rn0/3146246